# Find the max length of subsequence which has a number or its consecutive in recursion

Tags: java, recursion, subset

I am learning to program in Java and I have encountered a problem that I do not know how to approach:
Write a recursive function that takes an array and returns the maximum length of a specific sequence in that array.
that sequence has to include only **one number or two** which is its consecutive one.
examples of such sequences:

1. 1,1,1,1
2. 2,3,2,2,3,2

examples of not such sequences:

1. 2,3,4,2 (it has more than 2 nums)
2. 2,4,2,2(the 2nd number is not a consecutive one)

For example: if `arr=[1,2,3,2,1,0]`
the subsequences and their length will be:

```
a. {1,2}=2
b. {2,3,2}=3
c. {2,1}=2
d. {1,0}=2
```

therefore the function will return 3.

I thought about looking recursively on an array of 2 elements like [1,2] but then how do I recursively looking at bigger arrays?
thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is not understandable because of the grammer. Could you edit and fix it?

Comment: @wolfenblut edited :) maybe better

Comment: Just compare the numbers and keep two variables to hold the two numbers needed for the sequence to be passed along for comparison and return the sequence number to be compared to the previous sequence number.

Comment: @Dev what I understand now is that: You want to return the length of the longest **substring** that is in the following format: {a,b,a,b...,a,b} or {a,b,a,b...,a} or {a,a,...a}. Correct me if I'm wrong. Note: Substring(have to be continuous) and subsequence(doesn't have to be continuous) are different things.

Comment: @wolfenblut yes, only these are numbers and not letters.